# using regex to slash out initials in pattern

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to slash out pattern as specified using regex , but in replacement also replaces wanted character . specifying boundary does not help in this case .

```
 String name = "Dr.Dre" ;  
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(Mr.|MR.|Dr.|mr.|DR.|dr.|ms.|Ms.|MS.|Miss.|Mrs.|mrs.|miss.|MR|mr|Mr|Dr|DR|dr|ms|Ms|MS|miss|Miss|Mrs|mrs)"+"\\b");
     Matcher m = p.matcher(name);
     StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
     String namef = m.replaceAll("");    
     System.out.println(namef);
```

> Input : Dr.Dre or Dr Dre or Dr. Dre

### > output(expected) : Dre or Dre or Dre

Edit:

Thanks for help , but there is little regex issue I am facing:
Program:

```
String name = "Dr. Dre" ;  
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(Mr\\.|MR\\.|Dr\\.|mr\\.|DR\\.|dr\\.|ms\\.|Ms\\.|MS\\.|Miss\\.|Mrs\\.|mrs\\.|miss\\.|MR|mr|Mr|Dr|DR|dr|ms|Ms|MS|miss|Miss|Mrs|mrs)"+"\\b");
Matcher m = p.matcher(name);
String namef = m.replaceAll(""); 
System.out.println(namef);
```

For above program I receive output as: 
. Dre
while the desired output is :
Dre

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dot in a regular expression means "any character". You need to escape it with a backslash, which in turn needs to be escaped in a string literal:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Mr\\.|MR\\.|Dr\\.|mr\\.|DR\\.|dr\\.|ms\\."); // etc
```

Note that you'll end up with a double space after removing "Dr." from "or Dr. Dre" though...

EDIT: For some reason (I haven't worked out why), a space after a dot doesn't count as a word boundary. If you change your pattern to use `\\s` instead of `\\b`, so replace a single whitespace character, it works for "Dr. Dre" - but as noted in comments, it then fails for "Dr.Dre". You could either remove the word boundary entirely and add a space to the later parts of the pattern ("DR |Dr |" etc) or use `(\\s|\\b)` which works for the cases I tried it on, but may well have other undesirable side-effects.

Comment: @user595169: Um, your comment doesn't make sense - you've given the same input for both working and not working...

Comment: ops sorry correcting that :
1. input : Dr.Dre -> output:Dre
2. input : Dr. Dre -> output:. Dre

Comment: for input given as "Dr. DRE" i get output as ". DRE"

Comment: @user595169: You really shouldn't, and I didn't when I tested it. Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating this - edit it into the question. I'd expect output of " DRE".

Comment: @user595169: That's because you've still got `"|MR|mr|Mr|Dr|DR|dr|ms|Ms|MS|miss|Miss|Mrs|mrs"` in the pattern. You need to make the group capture more greedily - will see what I can do.

Comment: @user595169: Actually, it's the combination of the group and the word boundary. For some reason it looks like a space after a dot isn't counted as a word boundary. If you use `\\s` instead of `\\b` (so whitespace) then it works.

Comment: yes it will work with \\s but in case of Dr.Dre without space it will fail
another line need to be added in order to remove .<space> in this case

Comment: @user595169: That's true. But in that case, I suspect you're actually matching "Dr" as the abbreviation and "." as the word boundary. `(\\s|\\b)` works for the examples you've given here, but may fail elsewhere. Why not just make the "Dr" part in your pattern "Dr "? Are there other case you want to catch?

Comment: thanks for help ... this is still undone . can u explaing for input williams it removes ms and return willia how to avoid this .what should i do to tell my regex this must be for the complete word

Comment: @user595169: Possibly put a word break at the *start* of the pattern? (I suggest you take a step back and try to document *exactly* what you need. Stack Overflow isn't a good fit for keeping coming back with separate requirements.)

Answer (score 2):

The question is a bit unclear (you aren't providing the problematic results), but my guess is that the problem lies in using the period character. The period has a meaning in regex - it matches ANY character, so "Dr." will actually match **Dr.D**re. You have to escape it like so "Dr." or in your code specifically, to escape the escape slash, like this: "Dr\."

Hope that helps!